# angular.js navigate based on condition

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an application, lets say with 3 menus. `Home`, `Work` and `School`. The user can decide, what he's gonna do, go for working or to school. Each of them takes time, e.g 6 hours. When work is in progress, and the user clicks (or navigates to) school, I want the user stay on the same page and show a popup warning him about the work in progress. Same for school, if user clicks on work, I want him to stay on the current page, whatever it is (home or school). I'm using `angular ui-router` for routing purposes.

```
     $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/home',
                controller: 'homeCtrl'
                templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
            })
            .state('work', {
                url: '/work',
                controller: 'workCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/work.html'
            })
            .state('school', {
                url: '/school',
                controller: 'schoolCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/school.html'
            })
```

There's a status variable, which tells what the user is doing at the moment. This status variable can be reached from anywhere by using a service which is called State.

```
var status = State.status;
```

where 1 = user in school, 2 = user in work, 0 = user is idle. How could I stay on the same page and just open a popup based on condition instead of navigating to the selected page?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a function that is called on clicking the link instead of using `ui-sref`. Then you could make the necessary steps in your function.

Another option is to use ui-routers events or transition-hooks (if you are using >=1.0.0-alpha of ui-router). Then you could make your checks during the transition and cancel if needed.

If you have a menu that controls all transitions, using the first option would be easiest. However, if your links are scattered all over your app. You might want to look into the second option.

E.g. for Option 1:

```
function redirect() {
  if (State.status === 0) {
    $state.go('mytargetstate');
  } else {
    // do something else...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is `$scope.$watch`, and instead of having 3 different states you should only have one. If you want the URL to be different for each modal, then you will need to set up your main state in `$stateProvider` as follows:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('main', {
        url: '/:context', // Dynamic parameter
        controller: 'mainCtrl'
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html'
    })
```

This will allow you to have a single state with dynamic context. So the url would still be `/home`, `/work`, or `/school`, but would use one template, `views/main.html`. Then inject `$stateParams` into your controller, and access the context by using `$stateParams.context`. Like so:

```
State.status = $stateParams.context;

// then open the modal based on the $scope.State.status
```

You could also try using `$scope.$watch()` in your controller to watch a scoped variable for changes. A combination of these approaches would yield the best results.

```
$scope.$watch('State.status', function() {

    switch( State.status ) {
        case 'school':
            // open school modal
            break;
        case 'work':
            // open work modal
            break;
        case 'home':
            // open home modal
            break;
        default:
            console.log('wat');
            break;
    }
});
```